# Searching a range of cells for each nonzero value and then returning that value AND corresponding data in row/column where data intersects?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to search the range of values from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbr11.png) and return a few data points.

The output I'm hoping for would look like:

- 6/23 Pool 76
- 6/25 Recreation 76
- 7/2 Volleyball 13
- etc etc etc

Is there a function that would search down column G, move to column H, and so on?

I've tried vlookup/hlookup but that only returns the first value and I can't figure out how to also pull the data in column F and row 2 as well. Same sort of confusion with index and match functions as well as query which I don't think I totally comprehend. Any help would be so appreciated!

Also the data in that range is already the result of using the filter function on a much more complicated spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within sheets you may try:

```
=tocol(index(if(G3:R6,text(G2:R2,"m/d")&" "&F3:F6&" "&G3:R6,)),1,1)
```

***Adjust the ranges in the formula as per the dataset in your sheet***

[image]

Comment: That's incredible, thank you!! Would you be willing to talk me through exactly what's going on in the formula?

Comment: And a follow up question if that's alright - is there a way to separate those three data points into separate columns? I can use text to column with spaces as a separator, but in another sheet where I hope to use this formula, the activities have multiple words in their titles.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/slG8JFY.png As shown in the screenshot when a value is found in the defined range of G3:R6, it is to append the column F and row 2 date header. Once that is done tocol arranged them in single file by scanning column wise and removing blanks

Comment: try this to split the o/p into 3 columns: `=index(split(tocol(if(G3:R6,text(G2:R2,"m/d")&"|"&F3:F6&"|"&G3:R6,),1,TRUE),"|"))`